# how to draw $\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$ with tikz

Tags: plot, tikz-pic

I try this but it doesn't work

```
\def\Xmin{-2} \def\Xmax{2} 
\def\Ymin{-2} \def\Ymax{2} 
\def\Xunit{1.5cm} \def\Yunit{1.5cm} 
\def\Xleg{\small \sffamily $x$} % légende en abscisse 
\def\Yleg{\small \sffamily $y$} % légende en ordonnées 
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\Xunit,y=\Yunit] 
\draw[>= latex,->,thick](\Xmin,1)--(\Xmax,1); 
\draw[>= latex,->,thick](1,\Ymin)--(1,\Ymax); 
\draw [domain=\Xmin:\Xmax,thick,red] plot (\x,{(ln(\x+(sqrt{((\x)^2}-1)))});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: So, as a summary of the discussion below the answer: you can use this if you start the plot at one (the axes can remain the same): `\draw [domain=1:\Xmax,thick,red] plot (\x,{(ln(\x+(sqrt{((\x)^2}-1)))});`. But using `pgfplots` is better, because then you get automatic axis, labels, legend etc., and the function will be left blank at areas where it is undefined instead of giving errors like the Tikz-only approach.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do by hand what LaTeX can do for you, use `pgfplots` to add better plotting features including automatic axis

Note that without `pgfplots` *is* possible, but it does not have the save build in checks. For example in the proposed domain [-2,2] the function `x+sqrt{x^2-1}` cuts into negative numbers on which `ln` is not defined. And we would get the error

```
! Package PGF Math Error: I cannot calculate the logarithm of -0.26794
```

But `pfdplots` have build in checks so things does not blow up, so here giving it the domain of `[-2,2]` will work, `pgfplots` will just not plot anything in the affected area.

You may want to manually add `ymin` and `ymax` in the `axis` options like I did with `xmin` etc.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    unbounded coords=jump,
    domain=-2:2,
    xmin=-2,
    xmax=2,
    ]
    \addplot[red,smooth] {ln(\x+(sqrt((\x)^2-1)))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here is an example showing the original function and the behavior of the inner function.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    unbounded coords=jump,
    domain=-2:2,
    axis lines=middle,
    legend style={at={(-0.015,0.95)},anchor=north west,cells={anchor=west}},
    ]
    \addplot[red,smooth,samples=1001] {ln(\x+(sqrt((\x)^2-1)))};
    \addlegendentry{$\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$}
    \addplot[blue,smooth,samples=1001] {x+sqrt((\x)^2-1)};
    \addlegendentry{$x+\sqrt{x^2-1}$}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: we can't use my proposition ?

Comment: @lindaOiladali we can just a wast of time not using the build ins

Comment: @Marijn yes, I misread your comment.

Comment: @lindaOiladali if you add `\draw [domain=-2:2,thick,red] plot (\x,{(ln(\x+(sqrt{((\x)^2}-1)))});` after `\end{axis}` in my example (`axis` is special), we get the error `! Package PGF Math Error: I cannot calculate the logarithm of `-0.26794' ` and thus my preference for `pgfplots` here.

Comment: @Marijn nope, typo, fixed, though did not change much

Comment: please if I want draw an other function which is define on ]-1,1[ how to write the domain ? thank you

Comment: @lindaOiladali that is for another question (though often I'd just use `-0.999:0.999`)